# How can I check with Google Apps Script whether the sidebar opened by "SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);" is open or not open?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, sidebar

Background: The sidebar cannot be opened with onOpen().

"PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();" should not be used because it is only suitable for one user (possible overlaps). If the sidebar is open, nothing should happen to prevent it from being reloaded, otherwise it should be opened. A global variable could not be overwritten within a function for the next execution.

```
function sidebar() {
  if (? == 'off') {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Title');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `getUserProperties()` it works per user per script. A sidebar can be opened with onOpen() by adding a trigger to the respective script for onOpen() at https://script.google.com/home/.

```
var status = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); // global variable

function onOpen() {
  status.setProperty('sidebar', 'off');
  sidebar();
}

function sidebar() {
  if (status.getProperty('sidebar') == 'off') {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Title');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
    status.setProperty('sidebar', 'on');
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I understand, when the sheet is opened, sidebar property is set to off.  When the sidebar is opened it is set to on.  If I opened the sidebar, then closed the sidebar, then checked the property again, it would still say open as nothing has changed it back to 'off', correct?  I like the idea of using properties to monitor this, but I still haven't been able to find any information on a script that triggers when a sidebar is closed.

Comment: You can set up a function to close the sidebar and then execute the required actions (https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/01/09/closing-existing-sidebar-using-google-apps-script/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to work in this particular situation.  It's not perfect, but it is functional and pretty simple:

.html

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    google.script.run.collectPing();
    }, 10000);
```

.gs

```
function collectPing() {
  CacheService.getDocumentCache().put('sidebar', 'on', 15);
}
```

While the sidebar is open, it calls the server-side every 10 seconds and sets a property in the cache which lasts for 15 seconds.  You can then write a function on the server-side that looks at the cache and does something based on the cache property.  I just came up with this, so it is relatively untested, though my first try seems to indicate that it works.

Answer (score 0):

With Google Apps Script, Sometimes we want to avoid re/open a Window/Sidebar when a Window or Sidebar are open.

To flag as Open, we could use. As mentioned before, PropertiesService...

```js
const flag =  PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

function FlagWindowAsOpen(name)
{
  // you can use typescript and avoid this hack if you dev locally with Vscode
  if (typeof name!='string' || name==null || name==''){
    return
  }

  let windows = flag.getProperty('windows');
  if (windows===null) {
     windows = {open:[name]}     
  } else {
    windows = JSON.parse(windows);
    if (windows.open.indexOf(name)<0) {
       windows.open.push(name)
    }
  }
  flag.setProperty('windows',JSON.stringify(windows))
}

function FlagWindowAsClose(name)
{
  // you can use typescript and avoid this hack if you dev locally with Vscode
  if (typeof name!='string' || name==null || name==''){
    return 'Error: invalid name'
  }

  let windows = flag.getProperty('windows');
  if (windows===null) {
     return `${name} was not set as open`     
  } else {
    windows = JSON.parse(windows);
    let index = windows.open.indexOf(name);
    if (index>=0) {
       windows.open.splice(index,1);
       flag.setProperty('windows',JSON.stringify(windows))
    }
  }  
}

function isWindowOpen(name) {
  // again its not the better way, use typescript
  if (typeof name!='string' || name==null || name==''){
    return false
  }
  let windows = flag.getProperty('windows');
  if (windows===null) {
    return false
  }
  windows = JSON.parse(windows);
  return (windows.open.indexOf(name)>=0)
}

function getOpenWindows(){
  let windows = flag.getProperty('windows');
  if (windows==null) {
    return []
  } else {
    windows = JSON.parse(windows)
    return windows.open
  }  
}
```

The question is, how to set when windows Close?
Then the trick is put at your Html  code served  HtmlService....

```js
window.onunload = function () => {
    console.log("Closeing");
    google.script.run.FlagWindowAsClose('sidebar');
}
```

PS: Its a example code, need be refined to be use in production, but could be a start