# Open/close status of Google Sheets sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I am looking for a way to check the status of the sidebar in Google Sheets.

I understand I can check which sidebar html has been opened by setting a global variable before the html output is displayed. Since only one sidebar can be displayed at a time, this variable can be overwritten to correspond to the current open sidebar. I know that I can close the sidebar programmatically, but this does not prevent the user from closing the sidebar with the 'X' in the sidebar window.

The only viable solution I found was to repeatedly set a property value in the cache while the sidebar is open. Once the sidebar is closed, the open state property value can't be set, indicating the sidebar has been closed. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045366/how-can-i-check-with-google-apps-script-whether-the-sidebar-opened-by-spreadshe)

Is there a better/more efficient way to check the sidebar open/closed state?

Answer (score 1):

There are various events that fire before a page(sidebar) is unloaded.

- [`unload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)
- [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)
- [`pagehide` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event)
- [`visibilitychange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/visibilitychange_event)

The preferred/reliable way suggested by MDN is to use `visibilitychange` event to send a beacon using [`Navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). This can be caught server side with `doPost`. Other alternatives include `google.script.run`, but maybe unreliable than `sendBeacon`.

#### Related:

[Clear certain cells on Window Close AppScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883049/)

https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/